# Calling client-side function from google apps scrip

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I call a client-side function from google apps script (or if possible from google sheets)?

**js.html:**

```
function clientFunc (a, b) {
    return a+b
}
```

**code.gs:**

```
function server-func (x, y) {
    return somehowCall.clientFunc(x, y)
}
```

in google.sheet cell `A3`:

```
= serverFunc (A1, A2) // or clientFunc (A1, A2)
```

How can I achieve it. Is it possible? If not, what is best approach to designate some of heavy loads to client-side since my apps are becoming so slow when executing on google servers using all apps script.

PS: I know about `google.script.run` which runs server-side functions from client-side call. I want opposite of this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.
But even if it would, it won't help you.

The end goal I understand is to delegate some of the heavy loads to the client side.
By calling `clientFunc` from the server side, you're loading both the server and the client.

Also, when writting functions that are called like `=serverFunc(A1, A2)` they will always be server functions. There can't be a client function there.

If you want your scripts to run faster, do other kinds of optimizations, like minimizing the calls to `SpreadsheetApp` (or other libs).
Look for places where you call `openById`, `getSheetByName`, `getRange` etc. and make sure you're avoiding calling them from loops and minimizing these calls.

Those are the ones that are really slow. Any other pure javascript operation will run blazing fast.